# If $R$ is a ring and $M$ is a left simple $R$-module, then $R/\operatorname{ann}_R (M)$ is a left primitive ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

I'm attempting to prove that if $R$ is a ring and $M$ is a left simple $R$-module, then $R_1=R/\operatorname{ann}_{R}(M)$ is a left primitive ring. I know that this becomes trivial if $M$ is a faithful simple left $R_1$-module, but I can't seem to prove the faithful part.

Comment: What is your definition of a left primitive ring? Regarding the Wikipedia definition, the proof is almost trivial.

Comment: Yes, but I'm having trouble proving that M is faithful. I don't see how $ann_{R}M=0$.

Comment: Do you know how $R_1$ operates on $M$? Then just apply all definitions: Let $\overline{x} \in R_1$ with $\overline{x} m = 0$ for all $m \in M$. Then ... which implies ..., so $\overline{x} = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

If $M$ has the structure of a left $R$-module, then it also has the structure of a left $R_1$-module, given by the natural action
$$
\bar{a} \cdot x := a \cdot x
$$
for all $a \in R$ and $x \in M$. Since we are given that $M$ is simple, to show that $R_1$ is a left primitive ring it suffices to show that the above action of $R_1$ on $M$ is faithful.

But this follows almost immediately from the definitions: let $\bar{a} \in \operatorname{ann}_{R_1}(M)$, so $\bar{a} \cdot x = 0$ for all $x \in M$. But $\bar{a} \cdot x = a \cdot x$ by definition. So, $a \cdot x = 0$ for all $x \in M$, that is, $a \in \operatorname{ann}_R(M)$. Thus, $\bar{a} = \bar{0}$, or in other words, $\operatorname{ann}_{R_1}(M) = \{ \bar{0} \}$. Hence, the action of $R_1$ on $M$ is faithful, as was to be shown.